# How to calculate start and end dates of blocks of cells in Excel 2013?

Tags: excel

I have the following table in Excel 2013:

[image]

The column Dates consists of consequent 2-weeks intervals.
Other columns has coloured cells that indicate when the event lasts for different Addresses. For example, for Address 2 the event lasts from 13.01.2020 till 09.02.2020. I need to transform this table into the table with columns:

```
Start Date | Finish date | Address
```

For each Address there can be several time intervals during which the event lasts, so there can be several rows for each Address.

I can easily separate start and finish date of each 2-weeks interval with Text to Columns and I can fill coloured blocks with numbers for easier manipulation with cells. But I have no idea how to count the  start date and the length of blocks in order to count the end date of each block. I'm sure it can be done with some VBA coding but it isn't my strongest side. Is there a way to do it with built-in Excel functionality? The original table consists of about 50 addresses and 30 2-weeks intervals.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Power Query, available in Excel 2010+

In Excel 2013, if you don't have it, you may need to download a free Microsoft add-in to enable it.

***Put something in the Red blocks. I just used the letter `x` but they just have to be non-blank***

- Select a cell in the table
- Data / Get&Transform / From Table/Range
- Select the Dates column and `Split column by delimiter` : **-**
- Change type by Locale

  - you need to select `Date` and a locale that has the `dd.mm.yy` format
  - I chose Swiss-Alsatian but there are others
- Select the two Dates column and `Unpivot other columns`
- Then `Group By` the Address column and for Aggregation

  - `Min` of the Dates.1 column for start date
  - `Max` of the Dates.2 column for the End date
- Move the columns to your final design and rename them as needed
- Sort by the Address column

This can all be done from the UI

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Dates", type text}, {"Address 1", type text}, {"Address 2", type text}, {"Address 3", type text}, {"Address 4", type text}, {"Address 5", type text}}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Dates", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Dates.1", "Dates.2"}),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter", {{"Dates.1", type date}, {"Dates.2", type date}}, "gsw-CH"),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type with Locale", {"Dates.1", "Dates.2"}, "Address", "Value"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"Address"}, {{"Start Date", each List.Min([Dates.1]), type date}, {"Finish Date", each List.Max([Dates.2]), type date}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"Address", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

[image]

If you need to use formulas, the following should work:

Put your list of Addresses in, for example `G18:Gn`

In the formulas below, I defined a Table and used structured references, but you can use regular references if you need to.

I also, as in the above, placed `x` in the colored blocks. In this instance, it must be an `x`.  It can't merely be a `non-blank`

```
H18: =AGGREGATE(15,6,DATE(MID(Table3[Dates],7,2)+100,MID(Table3[Dates],4,2),LEFT(Table3[Dates],2))*1/(INDIRECT("Table3["&$G18&"]")="x"),1)
I18: =AGGREGATE(14,6,DATE(RIGHT(Table3[Dates],2)+100,MID(Table3[Dates],14,2),MID(Table3[Dates],10,2))*1/(INDIRECT("Table3["&$G18&"]")="x"),1)
```

And fill down as far as needed.

You get the same results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I solved my problem by myself eventually using similar technique. I also filled cells with identical numbers, used Text to Column, PowerQuery to unpivot the table and then - a couple of IF functions to find start and end dates. But thank you so much for this detailed answer!